# How to print after a match and until another match

Tags: regex, sh

I am trying to make a script in order to extract a certain number of lines from a large text file. I have an id-file containing id-numbers to look for in the main file, and when a match is found, I want to print out certain fields until the end character string is found. Then I want to look for all occurrences of text lines where the first line contains the same id-number before reading in the next id-number and restart the process until all id-numbers are tested.

The text file looks like this: (The beginning is not formatted correctly)

"part_1/group_01/p1_g01_f1_1_t-a0001"

1779    1866    h   Har
1866    1945    "A:
1945    1991    d`du
1991    2049    "}:
2049    2115    n   noen
2115    2260    ""u:
2260    2319    @
2319    2376    N
2376    2399    g   gang
2399    2514    "A
2514    2601    N
2601    2701    s   sett
2701    2768    "e
2768    2804    t
2804    2909    s   stokkmaur
7850    8906    <end>   <end>
.
"part_1/group_01/p1_g01_f1_1_t-a0002"
0   1617    <start> <start>
1617    1709    f   Frå
1709    1776    4
1776    1846    "O:
1846    1909    n   neste
1909    2013    ""{
2013    2101    s
2101    2177    t
2177    2216    @
2216    2286    v   veke
2286    2467    ""e:
2467    2549    k
2549    2601    @
2601    2755    "A: av
2755    2823    v   vert
2823    2930    "{
2930    2986    <end>   <end>`

The id-file looks like this:

a0002
b0507
c0576

and so on

So I want the script to find the first occurrence in the text file (trans.txt) containing the number a0002 and then print out everything until it matches the end string, then print out the next sequence of lines where the first line matches a0002 until all occurrences are found. Then I want to read in the next id-number from the id-file (b0507) and repeat the whole process until all id-numbers are read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one id search, you can use `sed` as follows, e.g.

```
sed -n "/a0002/,/<end>/p" file
```

Which suppresses the normal output until `a0002` is found and then prints all lines through the next occurrence of `<end>`.

**Output**

```
"part_1/group_01/p1_g01_f1_1_t-a0002"
0   1617    <start> <start>
1617    1709    f   Frå
1709    1776    4
1776    1846    "O:
1846    1909    n   neste
1909    2013    ""{
2013    2101    s
2101    2177    t
2177    2216    @
2216    2286    v   veke
2286    2467    ""e:
2467    2549    k
2549    2601    @
2601    2755    "A: av
2755    2823    v   vert
2823    2930    "{
2930    2986    <end>   <end>
```

To read all ids, separated by a whitepace character, from a separate *id-file* and find each id in a *parts-file*, use:

```
for i in $(< id-file); do
    sed -n "/$i/,/<end>/p" parts-file
done
```

Which will do the same thing for each id in the *id-file* (e.g. `a0002`, `b0507`, and `c0576`)

Comment: Sure, glad I could help. `sed` is a fantastic tool. If the answer helped, don't forget to select my answer as helpful by checking the green arrow at the top-left of the question.